# Linear independence of a special set of vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Let $$ S_1=(e_1,e_2,..,e_n)$$ a set of vectors.And suppose that $$ S_2=(v_1,v_2,..,v_n)$$
is linearly independent , where $$ v_i = e_i+e_{i+1} \quad if \quad 1 \le i \le n-1 \quad and \quad v_n = e_n+e_1$$
How can we show that if $$S_2$$ is linearly indenpendent then $$S_1$$ is linearly indenpendent as well ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $e_1=v_1-e_2=v_1-v_2+e_3=\dots\ $ write it out, then you can express $e_1$ by $v_i$. Then $e_2=v_1-e_1$, and so on..

> It turns out that $n$ must be odd. 
>  Then we have $\def\s{\mathrm{span}} \s(S_1)\subseteq\s(S_2)\subseteq\s(S_1)$, which has dimension $n$, so both $S_2$ and $S_1$ are bases of this common spanned subspace.

Comment: Wouldn't a $e_n$ be left will trying to express $e_1$ ?

Comment: An extra $e_1$ will be at the end. Depending on $n$ if odd or even, you can rearrange the equation to obtain $e_1$.

Comment: Thank you, but what if n is even , then the two $e_1$ would delete each others?

Comment: n can never be even , because if we suppose that , we will end up having a combination of $v_i$ that is null but  the coefficients aren't null ( one and minus one in this case)

Comment: Exactly. $\, \, $